# How to work on single gateway based microservice in a team?

Tags: java, jhipster, microservices

We are developing microservice based application using Jhipster. For that, there are different components should run at the same time i.e, service registry, UAA server, Gateway, and other different services. To run all these components on my PC it consumes all the resources (16 GB of Ram). However, other developers, they don't have sufficient resources on their PC, which is the reason we are facing the problems continues development in the team.
So we are seeking some options for this problem to get efficiency over our development team.

Currently, if someone wants to add/change features on the application, he needs to work with both microservice and gateway(for the frontend).
So, in this case, **what happen? suppose multiple developers are working on gateway and service at the same time in the development environment.
How are they going to debug/test?** do they have to deploy gateway individually?

We are planning to deploy microservices on our own VPS server and in near future for the production heroku, kubernetes, jenkins, cloudfoundry can be used.

Correct me if I am wrong and is there any better option for smooth development?

I had read Sam Neuman's Microservice book that the problem of the single gateway based application while development.Now I am very curious about how Jhipster came to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you are trying to work with your microservices as it was a monolith. One of the most important features in the microservice architecture is the ability to work on each microservice independently, which means that you do not need to run the whole infrastructure to develop a feature. Imagine a developer at Netflix who needs to run several hundreds of microservices on their PC to develop a feature - that would be crazy.

**Microservices is all about ownership**. Usually, different teams work on different microservices or some set of microservices which makes it really important to build good test design to make sure that whenever all the microservices are up and running as one cohesive system everything works as expected.

All that said, when you are developing your microservice you don't have to rely on other microservices. Instead, you better mock all the interactions with other microservices and write tests to check whether your microservice is doing what it has to do. I would suggest you **[wiremock](http://wiremock.org/)** as it has out-of-the-box support for Spring Boot. Another reason is that it is also supported by **Spring Cloud Contract** that enables you to use another powerful technique called Consumer Driven Contracts which makes it possible to make sure that contract between two microservices is not broken at any given time.

These are the integration tests (they run on a microservice level) and they have a very fast feedback because of the mocks, on the other hand, you can't guarantee that your application works fine after running all of them. That's why there should be another category of more coarse grained tests, aka end-to-end tests. These tests should be running against the whole application, meaning that all the infrastructure must be up and running and ready to serve your requests. This kind of tests is usually performed automatically by your CI, so you do not need all the microservices running on your PC. This is where you can check whether you API gateway works fine with other services.

So, ideally, your test design should follow the following [test pyramid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYbzQ.png). The more coarse grained tests you have the less amount of them should be kept within the system. There is no silver bullet if to speak about proportions, rough numbers are:

1. Unit tests - 65%
2. Integration tests - 25%
3. End-to-end tests - 10%

**P.S:** Sorry for not answering your question directly, I had to use the analogy with tests to make it more clear. All I wanted to say is that **in general, you don't need to take care of the whole system while developing. You need to take care of your particular microservice and mock out all the interactions with other services.**

Answer (score 1):

Developing using a shared gateway makes little sense as it means that you cannot use webpack dev server to hot reload your UI changes. Gateways and microservices can run without the registry just use local application properties and define static zuul routes. If your microservices are well defined, most developers will only need to run a small subset of them to develop new features or fix bugs.

The UAA server can be shared but alternatively you can create a security configuration simulating authentication that you would activate through a specific profile. This way when a developer works on one single web service, she can test it with a simple REST client like curl or swagger without having to worry about tokens.

Another possibility if you want to share the registry is to assign a spring profile per developer but it might be overkill compared to above approach.

Comment: Thanks for the very important feedback, now I can imagine the smooth development in the team.

Comment: So, what about the UAA server?  is it also mandatory to run UAA server along with gateway and services?